# How to run Monero as a private chain or a similar mode?

Tags: testnet, wallet

I am using msys2, am on a LAN and I don't want to connect to the public Monero network. My aim is to study Monero and so want to run it in a private chain mode or similar. So how can I run it like this? How to create the concerned environment? Thank you.

Thank you @jtgrassie, and I do it according to [here](https://github.com/moneroexamples/private-testnet). But in the first step I come across a situation: the wallet output stops after "WARNING: Do not reuse..." and does not show a prompt.

```
root@DESKTOP-EEM7CKJ MINGW64 ~
$ monero-wallet-cli.exe --testnet --generate-new-wallet ~/testnet/wallet_01.bin  --restore-deterministic-wallet --electrum-seed="sequence atlas unveil summon pebbles tuesday beer rudely snake rockets different fuselage woven tagged bested dented vegan hover rapid fawns obvious muppet randomly seasons randomly" --password "" --log-file ~/testnet/wallet_01.log --log-level 1
This is the command line monero wallet. It needs to connect to a monero
daemon to work correctly.
WARNING: Do not reuse your Monero keys on another fork, UNLESS this fork has key reuse mitigations built in. Doing so will harm your privacy.

Monero 'Nitrogen Nebula' (v0.16.0.0-c108c5e2f)
Logging to C:/tools/msys64/home/root/testnet/wallet_01.log
root@DESKTOP-EEM7CKJ MINGW64 ~/testnet
```

and the logs content is below: of course, I deleted some middle content in order to not exceed the length restriction.

```
 $ cat wallet_01.log
    2020-08-18 01:09:38.092 9692    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
    2020-08-18 01:09:38.092 9692    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:INFO,global:INFO,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO,perf.*:DEBUG
    2020-08-18 01:09:38.092 9692    INFO    msgwriter       src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  This is the command line monero wallet. It needs to connect to a monero
    2020-08-18 01:09:38.093 9692    INFO    msgwriter       src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  daemon to work correctly.
    2020-08-18 01:09:38.093 9692    INFO    msgwriter       src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  WARNING: Do not reuse your Monero keys on another fork, UNLESS this fork has key reuse mitigations built in. Doing so will harm your privacy.
    2020-08-18 01:09:38.093 9692    INFO    msgwriter       src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Monero 'Nitrogen Nebula' (v0.16.0.0-c108c5e2f)
    2020-08-18 01:09:38.093 9692    INFO    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet_args.cpp:211  Setting log level = 1
    2020-08-18 01:09:38.093 9692    INFO    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet_args.cpp:217  Logging to: C:/tools/msys64/home/root/testnet/wallet_01.log
    2020-08-18 01:09:38.093 9692    INFO    msgwriter       src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Logging to 
2020-08-18 01:09:38.288 9692    WARNING default src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132       EnglishOld word 'jaw' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2020-08-18 01:09:38.288 9692    WARNING default src/mnemonics/language_base.h:148       Duplicate prefix in EnglishOld word list: king
2020-08-18 01:09:38.288 9692    WARNING default src/mnemonics/language_base.h:148       Duplicate prefix in EnglishOld word list: mist
2020-08-18 01:09:38.288 9692    WARNING default src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132       EnglishOld word 'ode' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2020-08-18 01:09:38.288 9692    WARNING default src/mnemonics/language_base.h:148       Duplicate prefix in EnglishOld word list: path
2020-08-18 01:09:38.288 9692    WARNING default src/mnemonics/language_base.h:132       EnglishOld word 'pie' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2020-08-18 01:09:38.288 9692    WARNING default src/mnemonics/language_base.h:148       Duplicate prefix in EnglishOld word list: reve
2020-08-18 01:09:38.288 9692    WARNING default src/mnemonics/language_base.h:148       Duplicate prefix in EnglishOld word list: scra
2020-08-18 01:09:38.288 9692    WARNING default src/mnemonics/language_base.h:148       Duplicate prefix in EnglishOld word list: spir
2020-08-18 01:09:38.289 9692    WARNING default src/mnemonics/language_base.h:148       Duplicate prefix in EnglishOld word list: stra
2020-08-18 01:09:38.289 9692    WARNING default src/mnemonics/language_base.h:148       Duplicate prefix in EnglishOld word list: thro
2020-08-18 01:09:38.289 9692    INFO    mnemonic        src/mnemonics/electrum-words.cpp:237    Checksum is valid
2020-08-18 01:09:38.289 9692    INFO    mnemonic        src/mnemonics/electrum-words.cpp:163    Full match for language English
2020-08-18 01:09:38.290 9692    INFO    mnemonic        src/mnemonics/electrum-words.cpp:237    Checksum is valid

root@DESKTOP-EEM7CKJ MINGW64 ~/testnet
$
```

Maybe I cannot connect the testnet? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The following page comprehensively documents how to run a private testnet: https://github.com/moneroexamples/private-testnet

This allows you to run a private network of nodes (and wallets), which is exactly what you're after.

Comment: hi , I come accross a new question as above according to what you said.